# htaccess always uses the root folder rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to create some nice urls for my php search pages.

my current code:

```
RewriteRule    ^/search-jobs/?$    search-jobs.php    [NC,L]    # Search jobs page
RewriteRule    ^/search-jobs/jobs-in-(.*)/?$    search-results.php?location=$1    [NC,L]    # Search results locations page
```

matches /search-jobs with search-jobs.php, great
but it also matches /search-jobs/jobs-in-london to search-jobs.php, but I want it to match the second rule for search-results.php

Why is the first rule always used? and how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

none of the current answers have worked. I think my issue is that somewhere on my hosting (not accessible by me) there are some defaults set, as if i just go to /search-results, it will automatically use search-results.php file, although I have set nothing telling it to do so?

So, in theory, any /search-jobs(.*) query will automatically use search-jobs.php, seemingly regardless of any rules I create.

anyway, I rearranged my rules to the below.. and I still always hit search-jobs.php file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule    ^/search-jobs/jobs-in-(.*)/?$    search-results.php?location=$1    [NC,L]    # Search results locations page
RewriteRule    ^/search-jobs/(.*)-jobs/?$    search-results.php?keywords=$1    [NC,L]    # Search results keywords page
RewriteRule    ^/search-jobs/?$    search-jobs.php    [NC,L]    # Search jobs page
```

Comment: You still have a leading slash in the `RewriteRule` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Remove slash `/` from the beginning of request string like this:

```
RewriteRule    ^search-jobs/jobs-in-(.*)/?$    search-results.php?location=$1    [NC,L]    # Search results locations page
RewriteRule    ^search-jobs/(.*)-jobs/?$    search-results.php?keywords=$1    [NC,L]    # Search results keywords page
RewriteRule    ^search-jobs/?$    search-jobs.php    [NC,L]    # Search jobs page
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your second rule first, and also enclose your regexes in quotes.

That way when it matches ^/search-jobs/jobs-in(.*)/?$ the [L] flag says don't continue so it won't process ^/search-jobs/?$